# Randomly set the icon based on selection

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a Java Calculator Program. I want to randomly set the icon based on selection (50%/50%).

I know I use `setIconImage(image)` (extends `JFrame`). I have static

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/bulb.gif");
```

Choose that over;

```
static Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/calculatorIcon.gif");
```

as random chance each time the program gets opened?

Comment: I have; static Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/bulb.gif"); Not "I have static" (JFrame Btw)

Comment: Have a look at "java Random" on internet.

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                ((System.currentTimeMillis() % 2) == 0) ? "images/bulb.gif" 
                                                        : "images/calculatorIcon.gif");
```

Comment: Exuse me for asking but what does "?" and ":" do in this situation?

Comment: This is a a ternary shortcut in Java which basically equivalent to and if-then-else. http://java.about.com/od/t/g/ternaryoperator.htm